# How to separate date and time in php when displaying data in loop

Tags: php, date, datetime

I can't figure out how to separate the date and time when displaying the data from the database table.

```
if($num>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CNIC'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dt'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: There's no "date" in your code. Or does `$row['time']` contain the date and the time? In which format?

Comment: Sorry its ['dt'] instead of ['time'], I was just trying some stuff and forgot to replace it. I will update it rn

Comment: Show a sample data of $row['dt'] please

Answer (score 0):

If your `dt` field contains a properly formatted datetime string (i.e. the MySQL column data type is set to `datetime`) then you can create a new `DateTime` object in PHP and format it however you want.

```
$dt = new DateTime($row['dt']);
$time = $dt->format('h:i:s');
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -1):

After the `while`..

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", $row['dt']);
$time = date("h:i:sa", $row['dt']);
```

then use those variables.

It works when `dt` is a unix timestamp or parsable date format.

Comment: Still not working. This is the error it gave

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\ViewTable.php:54 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\form\ViewTable.php(54): date('Y-m-d', '2022-09-07 13:0...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\ViewTable.php on line 54

Comment: @muhammadabdullah The reason for this error is that you never told us what is stored in `$row['dt']`. We now know it is a string, but we still don't know the format. We can guess, but should we?

Comment: That was my bad. I didnt mfully understand it. I have found the solution to it tho